# How to get the right premissions for StartSpeakerEnrollmentJob in AWS connect VoiceID?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I'm trying to use `VoiceID's` API and I get the next error when I try to use

```
StartSpeakerEnrollmentJob: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the StartSpeakerEnrollmentJob operation: The service was denied access when trying to assume the provided data access role with ARN:
```

I use Python for my scripts.

I have created a Domain with a KMS key for Voice ID and gave the KMS key every permission there is available.
I uploaded my recording to S3uri and gave `StartSpeakerEnrollmentJob` the input URL and the output URL with DomainId and `DataAccessRoleArn`.

I'm expecting to receive some feedback from aws about the recording.